# Pass $_GET variable on form submit - PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Below is how I pass a variable to my url;

```
<li><a href="blog-admin-users.php?source=add_users">Create Users</a></li>
```

From the above, my variable is `source=add_users` and so the page can get it by checking `$_GET[source]`.

How do I achieve this with a html form.

My form below;

```
<form method="post" action="nextpage.php" class="search-form">
<div class="grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-100">
<label for="cuisine">LOCATION</label>
<br/>
<div class="select-wrapper">
<select name="location" id="location-select">
<option value="0">Central</option>
<option value="1">Garki</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-50">
<label for="day">DAY</label>
<br/>
<div class="select-wrapper">
<select id="activity" name="activity" onchange="changeTime(this);">
<option value="0">Central</option>
<option value="1">Garki</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-33 tablet-grid-33 mobile-grid-50">
<label for="time">TIME</label>
<br/>
<div class="select-wrapper">
<option value="0">Central</option>
<option value="1">Garki</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="availability-container" class="grid-100">
<input class="find" type="submit" value="FIND FOOD" id="searchfood">
<div class="error" id="notification"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

When a user clicks on submit, I want it to navigate to page

```
http://www.test.com/nextpage.php?location=1&day=today&time=12:00
```

My form has 3 select tags I want to pass the option the user selected to the next page in the url so the next page can use `$_GET` to use them in a mysql query.

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: relevance to jquery and ajax tags is? Edit: removed. Show relevance then add them back in respectively. Nothing to support the question/code.

Comment: Did you try leaving off the `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag?

Comment: Also, `action` would need to point to the right page `nextpage.php`, presumably...

Comment: Also, I hope when you say *"...so the next page can use $_GET to use them in a mysql query"* you mean by way of prepared/bind statement using a `mysqli_` or `PDO` connection...?

Comment: Use `method="get"` instead of `method="post"`, and the form inputs will be sent as URL parameters.

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm now using GET as the action and I can see all the options in the url in the next page.

Comment: and `$_GET[source]` possibly quoting it `$_GET['source']`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I'm using that now and I can see all in the url of `nextpage.php`

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes all my queries are secured against SQL Injection

Comment: Then as Tony would say *Thheeeeerrrreee GREAT!*

Comment: @Rasclatt Not the *"poop"* I hope?! Like Poop Tarts

Comment: @Fred-ii- No no no........the "*toot*"

Comment: @Rasclatt I've never heard of Toot Tarts! Sweet Tarts yes, but Toot Tarts?! On second thought, I might like those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They are imported from Mozambique...I only get the good stuff.

Comment: @Rasclatt I rather Betty Boop Tarts myself, but she's in another world now. And.... what about Columbia?

Comment: @Fred-ii- True....it really is *toot* bad *toot*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

Option one is to change the form to `method="get"`, and simply send everything as a `$_GET` request.

The second option is to append your `$_GET` to the end of the form's `action`. Since you specified that you want the user to be able to select which page they want to go to, you will need a bit of JavaScript.

In [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can change the form's `action` with the `attr()` method.

```
$('form').attr('action', 'nextpage.php?location=' + location + '&day=' + day + '&time=' + time);
```

Comment: I think jQuery may be heavy handed on this one. A simple form change is better.

Comment: that's not true at all.. look at my answer. you can absolutely send both post and get at the same time.

Comment: @Adelphia that's what explained in my second option.

Comment: well, i didn't dispute the second part of your answer. I disputed the part where you said "you can't do post and get at the same time" .. anyway, removed my downvote now that you fixed it//

Comment: @Adelphia I phrased it badly, my mistake.

Comment: I disagree that JQ is heavy handed - assuming it's already included in the page. I like the idea of changing the forms attribute dynamically. You could wrap that up into a little funtion to execute hybrid POST/GET forms :)

Answer (score 2):

in your form action you can send GET values the same way.

```
<form method="POST" action="poop.php?poop=poop">
```

Comment: why not *toot toot toot!* ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmmm....valid point...I hope Adelphia has a good explanation for that.

Comment: the p and the o are right next to each other. slightly easier than foo and bar, which require me to type with 2 hands :P

Comment: oh, like OOP stuff, but with a zesty twist, ahhhh yes, I get it now.